# Detect when bug is accepted in a specific board

Tags: jira, slack-api, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, python-jira

I'd like to know if it's possible detect when someone accept a bug ticket, is there any way to detect it? I mean I'm creating a bot for slack which should notify me when a jira bug is accepted so I can get the details from that like Assigned to : X Prioirity : X, etc, it is possible?

In one sentence : I'd like to know if I can detect and send a message via slack when someone accepts a bug ticket on Jira.

Comment: What you mean by "someone accepts a bug ticket on Jira"? How does the acceptance of bug ticket on Jira is done currently? Does the accepter move the ticket from once state to other and you call it "accepts"?

Comment: Yes it does pretty much like this, when someone changes the state of a ticket to "Accept" I want to print the assigned priority etc...

Comment: There are multiple discussion along this need. Are you able to find some help from these resources. Check them out 
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Webhook-not-giving-events-to-slack-com/qaq-p/68331
- https://www.opsview.com/resources/engineering/blog/jira-notifications-slack
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Post-each-project-update-to-1-slack-channel-multi-channel/qaq-p/699735